# Seeking database of all German cities with latitude and longitude

Tags: data, germany

Does anyone know a service that provides this or has advice how to obtain it myself?

Ideally free.

Comment: I think this would be better to ask at [OpenData SE](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/). Did you have a look at Openstreetmap data?

Answer (score 1):

All politically independent communities with selected characteristics at 30.09.2019
https://www.destatis.de/DE/Themen/Laender-Regionen/Regionales/Gemeindeverzeichnis/Administrativ/Archiv/GVAuszugQ/AuszugGV3QAktuell.html